# how to generate an ROC curve given a specific hit rate and false alarm rate on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, curve, roc

So I have a certain hit rate and false alarm rate, and I'm looking to see if there is a function that will allow me to type in thee two values and have matlab generate an ROC curve for me based on this point? Note, the hit/false alarm rates aren't extreme values, so curve estimation should be doable with one point, right?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you have these values for every possible cut-off of your classifier?

Comment: Curve estimation (of any kind of curve in any scenario) is *impossible* with one point. As calimo said, you need these numbers of a number of cutoffs in order to generate the curve.

Comment: thanks... is there any way then to just manually add a curve on to a coordinate axes then? and also to plot a dot at a certain location? I know exactly what points I want the curve to go through, so if there is a way to just draw it on, then that could work.